# storing unicode in c++ charcaters

Tags: c++, unicode, char

`char` in `c++` has a memory of `1 byte` but most of `unicode` characters require `2 bytes`.
Does this mean that `unicode` can't be stored in `characters` in `c++`?

Comment: It can be translated to utf8. utf8 can store all the characters in byte array.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To represent the character you can use Universal Character Names (UCNs). The character `'ф'` has the Unicode value U+0444 and so in C++ you could write it `'\u0444'` or `'\U00000444'`. Also if the source code encoding supports this character then you can just write it literally in your source code.

```
// both of these assume that the character can be represented with
// a single char in the execution encoding
char b = '\u0444';
char a = 'ф'; // this line additionally assumes that the source character 
              // encoding supports this character
```

Printing such characters out depends on what you're printing to. If you're printing to a Unix terminal emulator, the terminal emulator is using an encoding that supports this character, and that encoding matches the compiler's execution encoding, then you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, ф or \u0444!\n";
}
```

you can also use `wchar_t`

Comment: `char b = '\u0444';` won't work in most implementations, as `char` isn't that wide

Comment: Depends on compiler. On MS VC will work if codepage is 1251.

Comment: it is not compiler depended by LOCALE dependend, so it works on some machine and it files on other depending what kind of encoding locale uses. Since other systems are using UTF-8 it won't work there, and on Windows it works sometimes.

Comment: @MarekR agree, depends on encoding used. However, in clang missing the encoding is an error, in MSVC - a warning.

Answer (score 2):

no `char` isn't the only. If you are on Windows there is `wchar_t` ([`WCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269344(v=exchg.10).aspx)) or generally consider that `short` is 2-bytes also, but it's more about the way you want to implement and use it, the protocol ex:

```
#if !defined(_NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED)
typedef unsigned short WCHAR;
#else
typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
#endif

WCHAR* strDemo = L"consider the L";
```

but you need to dig more on web. they are also called **multi-byte string** so consider that in you searchs.

ex:

like in more general old-school cross platform BSD way:

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=multibyte&apropos=0&sektion=0&format=html

> http://utf8everywhere.org.     and do not miss this

also since you asked the question at first place I assumed you should know about **[boost](http://www.boost.org)** too.

Answer (score 1):

C, C++ also support 16-bit character type `wchar_t` used for unicode utf-16.

Often via Macro define `WCHAR` Or `TCHAR`.

You can force 16-bit character literal / source code constants:

```
wchar_t c = L'a';
```

and the same with 16bit character Strings:

```
wchar_t[256] s = L"utf-16";
```

Comment: `wchar_t` is not a 16-bit type, and it's not necessarily used for UTF-16. `TCHAR` is also not a standard macro

Comment: no, you didn't say that `wchar_t` is often a 16-bit type, and it's often not a 16-bit types on platforms other than Windows. The OP is not asking about Windows

Comment: `wchar_t` is 2 bytes on Windows, and used for UTF-16.  On most other platforms, `wchar_t` is 4 bytes instead, and used for UTF-32.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to be aware that there is something called encoding.
So there are multiple ways to represent non ASCII characters.

Most popular encoding nowadays is UTF-8 which represents single non ASCII character as multiple bytes 2-4. In this encoding you CAN'T store this kind character in single `char` variable.

There are other encodings where small subset of non ASCII characters are represented as single byte, for example [ISO 8859-2](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-2). Encoding is defined by locale and Windows is preferring such encoding, that is why `Java Rookie` answer had a chance to work for you.
Other systems are usually using UTF-8 for `std::string` so single character ca be represented by multiple bytes.

Another approach is to use `wchar_t` `wstring` `wcout` `wcin`, note there are still [some issues](http://www.firstobject.com/wchar_t-string-on-linux-osx-windows.htm) with that.